# Linux, alsa, usb audio device (Tascam US16x08), crashing when audio inputs are activating in DAW (Bitwig Studio)

Tags: bitwig

**Issue**

I have USB device Tascam US16x08 in Linux Ubuntu, Alsa drivers, all is ok, working and alsa even show everything about inputs, outputs and DSP! :)

When I select this device in Bitwig Studio (Alsa/US16x08), everything is working well until I turn on (record button) any input, for example IN 1 for guitar. After this (turn on any input) Bitwig Studio crashed.

Via `jackd` it is working, but why it is not working directly in Alsa? Where could be the catch? Or is there some log to analyze and search why it is crashing? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe try lowering your sample rate and bit depth? Or try increasing the buffer size?  (I have no experience with this list of tech specifically, so I'm going off of experience with my stuff.)

Comment: Start with increasing the buffer. This will increase latency, so shoot for less than about 13ms (without any effects added). You will probably perceive anything above 15ms as delay, and your hardware is probably going to be minimum of 2-3ms at best.

Comment: As far as adjusting your sample rate etc.: counter-intuitively, you might experiment by setting that to whatever is native to your chipset/DAC even if it is higher than 48k+16bit. Non-native implies potentially downsampling which adds latency. This helped me when using a realtek-based audio chipset on an older motherboard.